# Crontab does not run?

Tags: centos, cron

## crontab -e

```
0 */4 * * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
30 3 * * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
0  3 * * 1 root /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
30 2 1 * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```

## tail /var/log/cron

```
Jun 13 21:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2795]: starting 0anacron
Jun 13 21:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2806]: finished 0anacron
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups CROND[2810]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2810]: starting 0anacron
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2819]: finished 0anacron
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups CROND[2822]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2822]: starting 0anacron
Jun 13 22:01:01 web-backups run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2831]: finished 0anacron
Jun 13 22:44:59 web-backups crontab[2854]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jun 13 22:45:07 web-backups crontab[2854]: (root) END EDIT (root)
```

But I am not seeing my cronjobs run.

I can run the tasks manually and they run fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are using for your crontab is the `/etc/cron.d` format. When using `crontab -e` to edit the crontab, the username is not specified. The user used to run the job is the user that ran `crontab -e`.

Basically, change to this:

```
0 */4 * * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
30 3 * * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
0  3 * * 1 /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
30 2 1 * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```