# Crontab task not trigerred

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to automate backup management on server on raspberry and put a regular tar triggering into a crontab. I set it up via bash scripts. First I set up the task and then use script to carry out expected actions. The problem is the script isn't executed by crontab. When I run the same command as saved in crontab (I check it out with `crontab -l` command to be sure it's exactly the same) it all works properly.

Here is my backup script:

```
#!/bin/sh

function set_backup(){
    SCHEDULE_FILE="Configuration/crontab"
    SCHEDULE="* * * * *"
    USER=$(whoami)
    WORKING_DIRECTORY="$PWD"
    SCRIPT_NAME="/Admin/BackupHomeServer.sh"
    COMMAND=' /bin/bash ' #these spaces are essential for proper file formatting
    printf "$SCHEDULE " > $SCHEDULE_FILE
    #printf "$USER" >> $SCHEDULE_FILE
    printf "$COMMAND" >> $SCHEDULE_FILE
    printf "$WORKING_DIRECTORY" >> $SCHEDULE_FILE
    printf "$SCRIPT_NAME\n" >> $SCHEDULE_FILE
    crontab $SCHEDULE_FILE
}

function perform_backup(){
    BACKUP_FILENAME=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
    BACKUP_FILENAME+=".tar.gz"
    BACKUP_DIR=$(cat Configuration/PyHomeServer.conf | grep "Backup directory:" |  awk '{print $3}')

    FILES_TO_INCLUDE="Configuration/ Database/"
    if [ ! -d "$BACKUP_DIR" ]; then
        mkdir $BACKUP_DIR
    fi
    tar -cvzpf $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_FILENAME $FILES_TO_INCLUDE
}


function retrieve_latest_backup(){
    echo To be implemented
}

if [ "$#" = "0" ]; then
    perform_backup
elif [ "$1" = "retrieve" ]; then
    retrieve_latest_backup
elif [ "$1" = "set" ]; then
    set_backup
fi
```

This is what I see when I call `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash  /home/gonczor/Documents/ServerPy/Admin/BaskupHomeServer.sh
```

I've temporarily got rid of passing username after reading [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137070/crontab-does-not-run) and I've also ensured the path is correct after reading [this one.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206278/task-not-run-by-crontab)

Comment: 1) you want a backup very minute ? 2) there seems to be a missing / before home/gonczor/....

Comment: 1. It's just for testing. In target version I want user to be able to set own schedule.
2. Sorry, I was rewriting it from virtual machine by hand (shared clipboard refuses to work for some reason).

Comment: You're calling the script with `bash` but the top of the script itself declares that `sh` should be used. I suggest you amend the first line of the script to be `#!/bin/bash`. (It won't make a difference here (yet) but it's better practice.)

Comment: Use `=` only for comparing strings. Use `-eq` for numbers, i.e. `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then...`. It won't fix your issue here but it's good practice.

Comment: Quote your `"$VARIABLES"` when you use them. Unless you have a _really_ good reason not to do so. Otherwise unexpected characters (including whitespace) will break your script

Comment: `perform_backup()` uses a file `Configuration/PyHomeServer.conf`. What user runs your `crontab` entry? Is it the same user that has the Configuration directory in its `$HOME` or are you developing/testing as yourself but running the script as `root`?

Comment: Thank you for your "good practice suggestions", I'll implement them in a minute.
@roaima I'm not running anything as root here for security issues, so all is run by the same user having Configuration directory.

Comment: Your code `cat Configuration/PyHomeServer.conf | grep "Backup directory:" |  awk '{print $3}'` could be replaced by `awk '/Backup directory:/{print $3}' Configuration/PyHomeServer.conf`

Comment: `printf "$VARIABLE"` will break if `$VARIABLE` contains any of the formatting instructions used by `printf`. Either `echo -n "$VARIABLE"` or `printf '%s' "$VARIABLE"` would be safer.

Comment: Must get to bash scripting more carefully I see.

Comment: You may also find it helpful to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer in "How Linux Works" by Brian Ward. I've simply messed the syntax. Deleting the passing of `$USER` fixed the problem. In other words the file file I am passing to `crontab` should have following structure:

```
m h dm m dw command
```

and not:

```
m h dm m dw user command
```

And again thank you roaima for useful tips.